# ADODB failure when trying to access Fields

Tags: c#, ado.net, ado, adodb

I am using **CDO and ADODB** to generate **SMIL** for sending MMS messages. Everything was working fine but (I think) after some Windows Server 2008 R2 updates, things just stopped working with this error:

> Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type 'ADODB.Fields'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{00001564-0000-0010-8000-00AA006D2EA4}' failed due to the following error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).

**Here's where it breaks:**

```
private const string mcCDOContentLocation =
    "urn:schemas:mailheader:content-location";

part.Fields[mcCDOContentLocation].Value = "SMIL";
```

Any ideas? Maybe an alternative on how to generate SMIL documents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone is having the same issue, Microsoft provided a backwards compatible library, here's the solution:

[An ADO application does not run on down-level operating systems after you recompile it on a computer that is running Windows 7 SP 1 or Windows Server 2008 R2 SP 1 or that has KB983246 installed](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2517589)